# Find the sum of the values in data validation dropdown

Tags: google-sheets

What formula can you use to get check-boxes created through Data Validation to sum in a different cell?

Answer (score 2):

A spreadsheet formula cannot access the list entered in a data validation rule of another cell, and in particular cannot find the sum of the values in that list.

But you can use a custom function, like this:

```
function sumValidationValues(address) {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(address);
  var rule = cell.getDataValidation();
  if (rule != null) {
    var args = rule.getCriteriaValues()[0].map(Number);
    return args.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a+b;
    }); 
  }
}
```

Its argument is a string with cell address, e.g., `=sumValidationValues("A3")`

The method `rule.getCriteriaValues()` returns an object in which the first field is the array of acceptable values. This array is coerced to numeric if possible (originally they are strings) and summed.